# Azure Data Factory - Salesforce connection problem

Tags: salesforce, azure-data-factory

I have some issue with my ADF Salesforce connetor. Did anybody have it?

Operation on target Copy data1 failed: Failure happened on 'Sink' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorSalesforceOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=[BatchFailure]JobId:7503B000005V9v5QAC, BatchId:7513B000006IF3pQAG, Message:InvalidBatch : Field name not found : ConnectionReceivedId,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.SalesforceConnector,'

Comment: Sounds like field mappings are off or maybe your user doesn't have permission to see/edit all mapped fields. Unix vs Windows newline mess? If you go to SF -> Setup -> Bulk Data Load Jobs do you see better error msg? Maybe it'd even contain the CSV/JSON/XML files ADF tried to load so you could grab them, see if they're malformed, do they load ok in plain old Data Loader...

Comment: <error xmlns="http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload">
<exceptionCode>InvalidBatch</exceptionCode>
<exceptionMessage>Records not processed</exceptionMessage>
</error>

Comment: I have something like this

Comment: It seems like Azure is adding one field called 'ConnectionReceivedId' and it is not recognized by Salesforce :/ Any idea?

Comment: ConnectionReceivedId gets added in the SF tables if "Salesforce to Salesforce" feature is enabled. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_account.htm. See if you can edit the mapping to just not map to this field? Maybe somebody copy-pasted the ADF job definition from another SF org and for you best would be to start fresh?

Comment: Ok, i figured it out! Some of fields were not allowed to add. After deletion in mapping section everything works fine. Thanks for help

Comment: @RadosławMikołajczyk Congratulations that you figured it out! I help you post it as answer. You can learn how accept it ( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. You also could post yourself when you come back and I will delete mine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Congratulations that you figured it out:

" I figured it out! Some of fields were not allowed to add. After deletion in mapping section everything works fine"

I help you post it as answer and this can be beneficial to other community members.